# JavaScript and ajax.actionlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am working on an mvc application, 
i have a page that shows list of images and when you hover over the image it simply add border to the image  then i have some link on the page that filter the images 
these links are ajax.actionlink. it call a partial view and update the page with the result of the filtered images

but then i loose the hove effect i have specified on document ready

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function () {
                 $('.ListLi').hover(
                     function () {

                         $(this).children(".img-title").css("border", "3px solid black");
                 },

                 function () {
                     $(this).children(".img-title").css("border", "1px solid black");
                 }

                 );


             });


</script>
```

here is the ajax call

```
<ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix nav nav-pills" data-option-key="filter">

         <li class="active"><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">Show All</a></li>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

     @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.name.ToString(),"ListOfWorks","work",new { id=item.id },new AjaxOptions{
                     UpdateTargetId="List",
                      InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                      HttpMethod="Get"
       },null)
}

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Success` Callback in the `Ajax Options`

```
AjaxOptions
{
        UpdateTargetId = "List",
        InsertionMode  = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod     = "Get",
        OnSuccess      = "myCallback"
}
```

You can reuse this function in `DOM` ready.

```
function myCallback() {
    $('.ListLi').hover
    (
        function () {
            $(this).children(".img-title").css("border", "3px solid black");
        },

        function () {
            $(this).children(".img-title").css("border", "1px solid black");
        }
    );
}
```